# SSO SignIn page rendering with Email input element at top of page

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

When attempting to the load the default SSO SignIn page in Azure, the Email Address element is selected by default and in focus as follows;

[image: SSO SignIn Page]

When the page is zoomed the Email Address input is rendered at the top of the page on load, this causes tablets and smaller devices to be presented with a page that is already scrolled.

I have attempted to add a new input on a custom page and given it a tabindex of 0 (as a hack) as the default for all element contained inside the "api" div is 1.
I have also given the input element the autofocus attribute but it seems to strip both on render.

https://www.realmadrid.com/en/login is using a similar SignIn page and appear to have this function turned off, having gone through all the source that I could find it isn't directly apparent how they are achieving this.

Obviously this would be easy if it were possible to use JavaScript on custom pages in Azure B2C SSO but as this is not yet possible, does anyone know of a possible workaround or fix for this issue?

Update:

[image]

It's a little hard to illustrate using a screenshot, but if you select 'run now' on a new default 'SIGN-UP OR SIGN-IN POLICY' policy,  set responsive as per screenshot, scroll to the top of the page and press F5, you'll be able to see the stated behavior.

We are using heavily custom policies, I'm aware of how to do this, I'm using a default example for ease of replication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no longer an issue due to MS allowing front end JS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples