# Azure AD B2C Sign-Up HTML Autofocus

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am using custom policies for our sign-up/sign-in etc user flows. When navigating to the sign-up form in Chrome & Edge, the form displays scrolled part-way down the screen. I believe this is because the lowest input field (a check-box) has an  `autofocus` attribute, i.e.:

`<input name="xxx" id="xxx" autofocus="" type="checkbox" value="True" />`

I can verify that the lowest input (the checkbox) has focus as when I press the space-bar, it toggles.

It appears that Microsoft's javascript in the page is dynamically setting this autofocus attribute. Searching through the javascript it looks like every input has an `AUTOFOCUS=True` property:

`{
            "USER_INPUT_TYPE": "CheckboxMultiSelect",
            "IS_TEXT": false,
            "IS_EMAIL": false,
            ...
            "OPTIONS": [{
                    "DISP": "I agree.",
                    "VAL": "True",
                    "PRESEL": false,
            -->>    "AUTOFOCUS": true   <<--
                }
            ]
        }`

Is there any way to change this autofocus behaviour? Currently it is very annoying as it means that Chrome users see the bottom half of the form when the page loads.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this, I posted a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52377076/sso-signin-page-rendering-with-email-input-element-at-top-of-page

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Sorry no. I have not found any responses from the Azure B2C team on this anywhere :-(

Comment: Any updates on this? Two years later and I'm facing this same problem but with a button.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is essentially answered as JavaScript is now available for use on custom pages.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/resources/samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/

I'd suggest using JQuery to deselect the input element or remove the tab index value after rendering, but there are a myriad of options now available.

Comment: Couldn't find any reliable way to disable autofocus so far. Tried several options but due to B2C controls being rendered client side I've always run into race conditions (for example, I tried to remove `autofocus` attribute from all elements and call jquery `.blur()` on focued element but behavior was unpredictable). Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Probably depends on when my script is called vs when internal B2C script finished its work.

Comment: Maybe add a sleep to see if you can get consistent behaviour.